# What are the ramifications of having a MySQL client library that is newer than the MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project wherein the database is accessed by multiple applications running on different servers and written in different languages.

My portion of the project, the web interface, is written in PHP 5.5.9.
The other primary application is an Asterisk telephony piece written in PHP 5.3.3 and C.
The database server is MySQL 5.1.73.

It is, for various reasons, not realistic to update MySQL (and also out of my control).

So, My question is:
Are there any negative ramifications with this combination of older MySQL server and newer MySQL client library?

Comment: Short answer is - no. Long answer is - someone nitpicky will say yes, probably due to a reason that's absolutely not possible in real world. Both PHP versions have a library that implements MySQL's protocol, and during the connecting phase (handshake) you'll either connect or fail. If it fails because of your library (it won't, you have a pretty old MySQL to begin with) then you'll have to upgrade. I'm assuming nothing bad happened so far, therefore if it works - you're fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. I figured (and was hoping) that was the case.